# Journey Builder: how does 'end date' within Entry Schedule work

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I have created a journey which steps are completed after 2 days.

Steps include 3 email sends:

- 1st email send
- wait 3 hours
- 2nd email send
- wait 2 days
- 3rd email send
- wait 1 hour
- exit

Start date will be 03.15.2017

When setting up the entry source for the journey, I have selected "Email Studio Audience".

Have selected the Data Extension as the audience, no contact filter set up is needed, and for the entry schedule I have established that the end date is 03.16.2017.

Journey has to only look for new records and it will run on a daily basis.

**Question:**

The end date that I have established will stop new entries from being injected into the journey, but will not prevent pending emails sends from being completed for those entries that were injected prior to the end date.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you deactivate the journey on 14th, all the subscribers will be ejected out of he the journey immediately